# Pandas source code frame.py, using pipe or union operator

Tags: python, pipe, union

This line of code is from pandas/core/frame.py, line 632 at the current version ([pandas github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/main/pandas/core/frame.py)):

```
_hidden_attrs: frozenset[str] = NDFrame._hidden_attrs | frozenset([])
```

Can someone explain the `|` operator in this case?

I did try a very similar code in a notebook but got a `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'tuple' and 'frozenset'`

Comment: frozenset[str] is an annotation, indicating the type of the variable _hidden_attrs

Comment: `_hidden_attrs ` must be a `frozenset` as well. `frozenset` operators are described [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset): "Return a new set with elements from the set and all others".

Comment: true, thank you Carcigenicate. NDFrame._hidden_attrs is a frozenset too. 
chatGPT came up with this explanation when I asked why union with an empty frozenset: ok the answer is too long

Comment: They probably just have it like that in case it's not empty in the future. The union is already set up so they only need to change the one place to add hidden attributes if the need ever arises.

Comment: oh yes, of course. that could be a reason as well! thanks

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the comments, the | operator is used as a union operator in this case. The code creates a union set of NDFrame._hidden_attrs and an empty frozenset.
Why union with an empty frozenset, chatGPT answered:

- Making a union of a frozenset with an empty frozenset may seem counterintuitive because the resulting set will be the same as the original frozenset. However, there can be cases where this operation is used for specific purposes. Here are a few possible reasons:
- Standardization: In certain scenarios, it might be desirable to ensure that a frozenset is consistently represented as a frozenset, even if it is empty. By performing a union with an empty frozenset, you enforce the type and create a new frozenset object.
- Code Consistency: If there are other parts of the codebase that expect the variable to always be a frozenset, even when it's empty, performing a union with an empty frozenset guarantees that the variable remains a frozenset throughout the code. This can help maintain consistency and avoid potential errors or type inconsistencies.
- Semantics: Depending on the context and requirements of the code, an empty frozenset may have a special meaning or serve as a placeholder. By explicitly performing a union with an empty frozenset, it indicates that the set is intentionally empty and distinguishes it from other cases where the set might contain elements.

While the specific use case and intention behind this code snippet may vary, performing a union of a frozenset with an empty frozenset ensures that the resulting set remains a frozenset and can serve as a way to standardize or convey specific semantics in the code.